# My script for page loading bar, returns differently everytime of F5

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a free source progress bar, and I wrote a script for it.

the script is here,

```
var nanobar = new Nanobar( options );
var loaded = 0;
    var number_of_media = $("body img").length;

    doProgress();

    // function for the progress bar
    function doProgress() {
        $("img").load(function() {
            loaded++;
            var newWidthPercentage = (loaded / number_of_media) * 100;

nanobar.go(newWidthPercentage);
document.getElementById("showing").innerHTML = newWidthPercentage;
        })
    };  

    });
```

This. I think,
Loaded <-- (which gets + 1 every time an image finished loaded)
divided by
Number of total body images,,
and then multiplied by 100

So that this can make the percentage number of loading process.
Then I put that percentage number into the box of,
A Loading bar's destination point. (which is : nanobar.go( here ))

**But the bar moves werid**, 
*everytime I click the menu, it returns different.*
so I made a box to display the percentage number ( in the red box you can see in the picture )

I don't understand how this kind of random numbers are coming out every time.

### Please advice.

[image: random numbers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider....

```
6/7 = 0.8571428571;
0.8571428571 * 100 = 85.71428571;
```

So if you want to 'tidy' these long decimals, then you need to truncate the float. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

```
var num = 0.8571428571 * 100;
var n = num.toFixed(2);  
Then n == 85.71
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the comment, but that script must load every image on the body. so it always MUST be 7/7 or 100/100 or 200/200 unless there's a problem on internet connection.how come it comes out not loading every image on the body?

Comment: So just to clarify,.. the actual issue is that the percentage does not accurately reflect the quantity of images which are meant to be loading?

Comment: yes. that "was" the issue. thank you for your advice. after leaving this question, I was finding a solution myself, and I found this which was the answer. That head script is not correctly work because of cache and script working not always right. So, now it works well since I added onload function to every img tag.